# Merge Sort and Quick Sort issues

Tags: java, quicksort, mergesort

I thought this would be nontrivial, but its been awhile since I've done any java. My merge sort and quick sort algorithms (assignment for class) don't work! The array remains in the same order as before I call the methods. Any help is appreciated!

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class Main {
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // 
    Lab1Methods lab1 = new Lab1Methods();
    lab1.fillArray();
    lab1.testProblem1(lab1.integers);

    lab1.auxMergeSort(lab1.integers, lab1.startIndex, lab1.endIndex);
    lab1.testProblem1(lab1.integers);

    lab1.auxQuickSort(lab1.integers, lab1.startIndex, lab1.endIndex);
    lab1.testProblem1(lab1.integers);
    }
}

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab1Methods {
//**************************************************fields
int[] integers;
int startIndex;
int endIndex;

//**************************************************methods

//****************************************constructors
public Lab1Methods(){
    integers = new int [10000000];
    startIndex = integers[0];
    endIndex = integers[9999999];
}
//****************************************1***********************
    public void fillArray() throws IOException{
        FileReader file = new FileReader("lab1_data.txt");
        int i = 0;
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            while(input.hasNext())
            {
                integers[i] = input.nextInt();
                i++;
            }
            input.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    //**********test the first problem**********
    public void testProblem1(int[] array){
        int [] testIntegers = array;

        System.out.println("The first ten integers: ");
        for(int j = 0;j<10;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(testIntegers[j]);            
        }
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println("Sum of all 10,000,000 integers: ");
        for(int k = 0;k <= testIntegers.length; k++)
        {
            sum += k;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    //****************************************2****************************
     public void DoMerge(int [] numbers, int left, int mid, int right)
      {
        int [] temp = new int[25];
        int i, left_end, num_elements, tmp_pos;

        left_end = (mid - 1);
        tmp_pos = left;
        num_elements = (right - left + 1);

        while ((left <= left_end) && (mid <= right))
        {
            if (numbers[left] <= numbers[mid])
                temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];
            else
                temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];
        }

        while (left <= left_end)
            temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];

        while (mid <= right)
            temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];

        for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
        {
            numbers[right] = temp[right];
            right--;
        }
    }
    public void auxMergeSort(int[] array, int left, int right){

        int mid;

        if (right > left){
            mid = (right + left) / 2;
            auxMergeSort(array, left, mid);
            auxMergeSort(array, (mid + 1), right);

            DoMerge(array, left, (mid+1), right);
          }
        }

              //**********************************3************************
    public void auxQuickSort(int [] arr, int startIndex, int endIndex){
              // For Recusrion
              if(startIndex < endIndex)
              {
                  int pivot = Partition(arr, startIndex, endIndex);

                  if(pivot > 1)
                      auxQuickSort(arr, startIndex, pivot - 1);

                  if(pivot + 1 < endIndex)
                      auxQuickSort(arr, pivot + 1, endIndex);
              }
          }

    public int Partition(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex){
        int pivot = numbers[startIndex];
        while (true){
            while (numbers[startIndex] < pivot)
                startIndex++;

            while (numbers[endIndex] > pivot)
                endIndex--;

            if (startIndex < endIndex)
                {
                    int temp = numbers[endIndex];
                    numbers[endIndex] = numbers[startIndex];
                    numbers[startIndex] = temp;
                }
            else
                {
                    return endIndex;
                }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Where are `startIndex` and `endIndex` set?  What are they set to?

Comment: `startIndex` and `endIndex` alway 0 and that's why your program cannot run your sorting methods.